# Koin 2 problem with creating scope for feature in Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, koin

I try to create scope for a feature. I define a module like this.

```
val appModule = module {
    scope(named("ARTIST_SCOPE")) {
        scoped {
            ArtistRepository(get())
        }
        scoped {
            GetArtistsUseCase(get())
        }
        viewModel { ArtistViewModel(get()) }
    }
}
```

My goal is to make `ArtistRepository`, `GetArtistUseCase`, and `ArtistViewModel` only accessible inside `Artist Feature`.

In my activity

```
class ArtistActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val artistScope = getKoin().createScope("artistScope", named("ARTIST_SCOPE"))
    private val viewModel: ArtistViewModel by artistScope.viewModel(this)
...
}
```

My problem is when I leave this activity and return back to it.

I got this error.

```
org.koin.core.error.ScopeAlreadyCreatedException: A scope with id 'artistScope' already exists. Reuse or close it.
enter code here
```

How to reuse the existing scope?
or Am I implement the scope in the right way?

Comment: You need to close the scope

Comment: Closing the scope would be one option but I do want to reuse the existing one if possible.

Comment: Since you are creating the scope inside the activity, it can only be reused within that activity instance.

Comment: Ok, I guess I might have to do that. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`getOrCreateScope()`](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/api/koin-core/org.koin.core/-koin/get-or-create-scope.html). This will get an existing instance if you have one that isn't closed with the same scopeId, or it will create a new instance if it needs to.